# Using right shift key to make a cap minimises the window

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

My daughter's friends were messing with the keyboard and now the right shift key minimizes the screen every time I'm using the shift to make a cap with the my right hand.  Since I'm a touch typist this is really frustrating.

I have gone to keyboard preferences and hit reset default - not working. Suggestions?

I have a MacBook Air 2014 running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.